# AngularJS: $routeProvider configured, change controller scope value

Tags: angularjs

Have configured `$routeProvider` for Ajax response on certain URL pattern, also have added div element with controller mapping:

```
<!-- class="hidden" to keep element hidden till AngularJs is not ready -->
<div ng-controller="IModalCtrl" class="hidden" ng-show="is_visible" ng-view>
    <!-- AJAX RESPONSE VIEWER -->
</div>
```

On successful request, response content is appending to target <div> element, but element is not being visible due to `ng-show`, it's model value is not changing.

I don't know where to change the value of `$scope.is_visible`.

Below is the work:

```
var app = angular.module('home', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $routeProvider.when('/news/:cat/:slug/:id', {
        templateUrl: function (attr) {
            console.log(attr);
            return '/news/' + attr.cat + '/' + attr.slug + '/' + attr.id + '?ajax=1'
        },
        controller: 'IModalCtrl'
    }).otherwise('/');
}]);

app.controller('IModalCtrl', function($scope, $http, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
    // Keep element hidden default
    $scope.is_visible = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have created a two instance of `IModalCtrl` controller, as one of them is on `ng-view` div and the other one is loading from the route definition.  I don't think so the controller you are loading from the route definition is required.

To solve your issue you don't need to use `ng-show`, you need to `$scope.is_visible = true;` after the ajax gets succeeded from `IModalCtrl` controller.

**Update**

In such case you could take use promise, which will tell a controller to load when the resolve function gets completed its promise.

```
$routeProvider.when('/news/:cat/:slug/:id', {
    templateUrl: function (attr) {
        console.log(attr);
        return '/news/' + attr.cat + '/' + attr.slug + '/' + attr.id + '?ajax=1'
    },
    controller: 'IModalCtrl',
    resolve: {
       getData: function($http){
          //this will get called before controller get loaded
          //and the include this promise inside the controller.
          return $http.get('url'); 
       }
    }

})
```

Comment: Two instance!!! I've followed this docs [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route). 
That's my question is where do I put this code `$scope.is_visible = true;`?

Comment: @vinaykrsharma what you wanted to achieve by using declaring `is_visible` flag?

Comment: I want to make the div element visible after Ajax response appends!

Comment: then you need to use `promise` option of route